# Re and Im on a matrix

Tags: matrix, complex

I need to apply the commands `Re` and `Im` on a matrix. I have tried to use `ComplexExpand` on the `E` part, but it didn't work. The matrix is too big to do it manually.

Example of what I'm looking for:

```
 Re[{5 I, 1 I, 1}*E^(t*(-1/2 + 2*I))]
```

Comment: `ComplexExpand[Re[{5 I, 1 I, 1}*E^(t*(-1/2 + 2*I))]]` works fine on 11.3.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I had a stupid mistake, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already shown in the comments, you need `ComplexExpand`. The reason is that otherwise, Mathematica would not know that `t` is not a complex number itself.

As you are interested in both `Re` and `Im`, I suggest you try

```
ComplexExpand[ReIm[{5 I, 1 I, 1}*E^(t*(-1/2 + 2*I))]]
(* {{-5 E^(-t/2) Sin[2 t], 5 E^(-t/2) Cos[2 t]},
    {-E^(-t/2) Sin[2 t], E^(-t/2) Cos[2 t]},
    {E^(-t/2) Cos[2 t], E^(-t/2) Sin[2 t]}
} *)
```